# Why does computer hangs everyday?

Tags: linux, troubleshooting

My Linux computer hangs every day (sometimes twice a day). It also hangs my home network until the Ethernet cable is unplugged or I reset it. I can`t find any severe exceptions in log. This computer works in 24/7 mode. It holds torrent downloads, tomcat for my work and also play an HTPC role. How would I go about troubleshooting this issue?

Update1.

I use Gentoo.

UPDATE2.

Hangs happen at random time, mostly when nobody is using the computer. It shows the last image before freezing (screensaver, browser or whatever else), I can't do anything, and doesn't respond without a restart. `smartctl` shows that temperature gradually increased for 4-5°C in 5-10 minutes before it dies. I have 16GB of RAM and 32GB of swap (I planned to use `suspend on disc` function when make partition). 
Normally it holds smb shared folder, runs squid, deluge,tomcat and audio-video players in xfce environment.

Comment: Few things. What Linux distro are you running and have you checked to see what processes are running on your machine? Since you run torrent downloads it could have something to do with a process in p2p you're running.

Comment: I run gentoo distro. Torrent client is deluge wich use rb-libtorrent. Computer have two states. It works fine without any suspicious resource leaks or it can hangs and I can't even press ctrl+alt+F1 and open console to findout what happens.

Comment: Have you checked your CPU and RAM history to see if they are spiking?

Comment: Please describe the hangs, we have no idea what you're talking about. When do they happen? Are you doing something in particular? Does the computer eventually resume normally? Do you need to restart? Is it getting HOT? How much RAM do you have? SWAP? Can you do _anything_ while it's hung? Move the mouse? `ssh` to it? Use the console? Are you running a graphical desktop? Are you exporting any shares from the machine? To the machine? If you don't give us any information, how do you expect us to help?

Comment: Can you advise a program to collect  statistics?  Top and htop show only current values.

Comment: Your dmesg could provide some clues

Comment: @terdon Thanks for helping build the information requirements.

Comment: OK, please post the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, `~/.xsession-errors`, the output of `grep -i error /var/log/kern.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to run through some default troubleshooting steps and see if you get anywhere give  [these](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3301593) a try.

Once again I have no idea what system you are running, so this might not be exact, but it's a start.

Comment: I'll try memtest86+ these evening.

Comment: Ok. I had some failures when memtesting. I`ll try to fix em.